# Background process of Mulesoft

Tags: mule-component, anypoint-studio, mule-esb, mulesoft, mule-sdk

I would to learn what is happening on the background of mulesoft.

Example when we drag and drop a compent ie palette in Anypoint studio what will happen? I would like to see the Java code and how it works actually. Can someone give me clue or guide me where to start reading about it.

I have checked in the project path where there is a only xml files and no java files is present.

Thanks,
Vignesh G

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too open ended and wide in scope to probably have a simple answer. It is not clear if you are asking about how Anypoint Studio works at design time, or Mule Runtime at execution time. I'm assuming you are interested in the later. Mule Runtime is implemented in Java, but it doesn't generate Java code. If you are interested in the internals of Mule you can go to the open source repository and inspect the code: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule. It is not a trivial project by any means, so it is not possible to describe how it works in a comment.